# inf2cat driver signing for Windows 10 Enterprise?

Tags: windows, code-signing, drivers, inf, driver-signing

I can sign driver files just fine for everything but Windows 10 Enterprise. 10_X86, server, and X64 don't seem to be working on Enterprise.

Does it have a specific code to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`/os` switch in `Inf2Cat` specify the **Windows versions**, not the **editions**.
So you can use `10_X86` or `10_X64` for Windows 10 Enterprise.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/inf2cat#span-idswitchesandargumentsspanspan-idswitchesandargumentsspanswitches-and-arguments